# How to find this global definition with cscope when there are two functions which had the same name at different file?

Tags: vim, cscope

I read the code of redis with vim and build the database like this:

```
find . -iname '*.c' -o -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.hpp' > cscope.files
cscope -bq -i cscope.files -f cscope.out
```

and map keys in vim:

```
nmap <C-@>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```

When I read `src/dict.c` and want to find the definition of function `_dictInit`, it should locate to the definition at `src/dict.c`, but actually it locate to the definition at `deps/hiredis/dict.c`, which has the same name function definition

So how should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That occurrence of `_dictInit` in `deps/hiredis/dict.c` is the first entry in the database.

Since there are two entries you should get a list like this one:

[image: cscope result]

that allows you to choose which definition to jump to.

Comment: I set vimrc like this:`nmap <C-@>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>:copen<CR>` it would open quickfix window like you show, but it automatically selected 1st file to locate.

Comment: This is not the quickfix window: that's the normal output of a cscope query with multiple results and it's displayed in the command line. FYI, the screenshot was done with your mapping, using a database created with your snippets against the latest redis source.

Comment: I install the plugin `cscope.vim` and found that `set cscopequickfix=s-,g-,d-,c-,t-,e-,f-,i-`, after I delete `g-`, it was ok. Thanks.